# gedit: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: gedit, vim, bashrc, alias, ros

I am trying to make use of the alias command to separate the ROS1 and ROS2. I have dual-booted Ubuntu on my MacAir machine and am using the docker container, which I have installed both the ROS1 and ROS2.

`sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` (I have installed 'gedit' already)

Once I hit the command, I receive such error message.:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:17834): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:29:14.565: cannot open display:
```

It seems like the next step is just adding the two lines of bash script. Would it be possible to just add those two lines with VIM?